# Export range of columns to PDF page

Tags: excel, vba, range, export-to-pdf

I have the below script to export each excel sheet to a separate PDF page. It works fine, except for one small issue. I need the range Columns A:H to fit on one PDF page. How can I update the below script to make sure I export all information on one page for the specified columns?

```
Sub ExportToPDFs()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Select
nm = ws.Name

ActiveSheet.Columns("A:H").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:="C:\My Folder\" & nm & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the print area to A:H and set scale to fit to 1 page wide and 1 page high through the Page Setup part of the Ribbon. Then the following code should work without having to mess with the scaling through VBA.

```
Sub ExportToPDFs()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Select
nm = ws.Name

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:="C:\My Folder\" & nm & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next ws

End Sub
```